# How can I easily convert 139.29.0.0 to 139.029.000.000 at sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, masking

How can I easily convert 139.29.0.0 to 139.029.000.000 at sql?

Comment: What qualifies as "easily" ? - asking someone else on SO to do it seems pretty easy, but maybe not what you had in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be splitting by the dots, padding leading zeroes upto the 3 precision and then aggregating back such as

```sql
 SELECT LISTAGG( LPAD( REGEXP_SUBSTR(n,'[^.]+',1,level), 3, '0'), '.' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY level) AS IP
   FROM t 
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(n,'.')+1
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR n = n
  GROUP BY n
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=41fcb0cdd6ab5712dff03c8f67b5e7e4)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

There are different approaches.  One is to split the string into four numbers and then reformat them.

Another approach just uses regular expressions.  The following pads all the numbers with three zeros and then takes the last three digits before each `'.'` or the end of the string:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(ip, '([0-9]+)', '000\1'), '[0-9]*([0-9]{3}([.]|$))', '\1')
from (select '139.29.0.0' as ip from dual) x
```